# The "/**/*.js" pattern is no longer allowed in Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I refactored this piece of code, that was working well in Spring Boot 2.7

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**").and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
    "/",
                "/_admin/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html*",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/api-docs/**",
                "/api/**",
                "/login",
                "/login/**",
                "/oauth2/**",
                "/static/**",
                "/404",
                "/405",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/**/*.png",
                "/**/*.gif",
                "/**/*.svg",
                "/**/*.jpg",
                "/**/*.html",
                "/**/*.css",
                "/**/*.js")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/ui/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();

    http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().maxAgeInSeconds(0);
}
```

to this:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**").and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(true).dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll().requestMatchers("/",
                    "/api/v1/links/**",
                    "/_admin/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html*",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**",
                    "/swagger-resources",
                    "/api-docs/**",
                    "/api/**",
                    "/login",
                    "/login/**",
                    "/oauth2/**",
                    "/static/**",
                    "/404",
                    "/405",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/demoLink/**",
                    "/DemoLink/**",
                    "/templateLink/**",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js"
                    ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login();

    http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().maxAgeInSeconds(0);

    return http.build();
}
```

But I'm getting **PatternParse No more pattern...**

I am migrating to Spring Boot 3, but the issue that `/**/*.x` is no longer allowed which causes some redirections to be authenticated. I searched a lot but can not find the replacement of `/**/*.x` pattern in the new Spring Security.

**Edit:** I don't own the `.js` resources. I receive them while the service is doing some sort of redirection, so I can't predict a specific pattern.

Comment: Try like this
         `.requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/v1/links/**"),AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/_admin/**"),......)`

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately didn't work, thanks though

Comment: @Bassem I guess the Custom Authentication Filter or Custom Request Matcher solutions are the only two options if restructuring isn't an option. You can try my solution, I use it on my server and it works. The code I posted is simplified.

Answer (score 2):

I asked ChatGPT and got this:

In Spring Security 5.5+ (which includes Spring Boot 3.x versions), the use of the double asterisk (**) with file extensions in the pattern (like /**/*.js) was deprecated because of concerns with its implementation and interpretation.

Use explicit paths: Instead of /**/*.js, you can use patterns like /js/** or /css/** assuming you keep your JavaScript files under /js/ and CSS files under /css/

Maybe you have to restructure a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @Mergo but this pattern also is not valid for spring security.

Comment: also here, I don't have a specific js files, I got them from 3rd parties while redirection

Comment: But I am using Spring 3.1.0 and for me this here is valid:

.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/confirm/**").permitAll()

Comment: the "/confirm/**" would work normally, but the /**/*.js pattern is no more allowed, why I need to use the /**/*.js pattern? cause the service is make some sort of redirections, so I can't predict what I am receiving, and certainly I need to exclude them from being authenticated

Comment: Mhmm Okey, that makes things a bit complex. Maybe you can implement a custom RequestMatcher. 

`http.requestMatchers(new RequestMatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        return path.endsWith(".js") || path.endsWith(".css") || /* any other conditions */;
    }
}).permitAll();`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your custom authentication filter and thus intercept the request before it gets into the actual filter. There you can check your conditions and authenticate the request yourself.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if ([your condition])) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new 
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, null);       
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response); //send it to the filter.
    }
}
```

You also have to add this in the filter chain in the other class:

```
.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```